# Why am I not seeing any increased performance when making async calls to database from django?

Tags: django, asynchronous

Django itself is synchronous, but I recently started a new Django project and decided to set it up from the ground up being asynchronous, that meant that I followed most of the django-channels design, with channels own async http-consumers and protocol router, and instead of using daphne I ran gunicorn with uvloop workers.

One thing that became apparent was that using the ORM for queries to my database was not async. There was no information online about how to solve this, so I thought why not use a external async postgres client package (`aiopg`), and pass the ORM generated SQL query to `aiopg`, and then just convert the results back into the django model instances. It worked, but using apache bench before and after using async aiopg, I saw absolutly no increase in requests per second.

The following code shows how I did it.

```py
import aiopg

dsn = 'dbname=db user=root password=password123 host=postgres-container port=5432'
pool = aiopg.create_pool(dsn)


async def async_query(q):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(q)
            ret = []
            async for row in cur:
                ret.append(row)
            return ret

async def list(self, body):
    query = Model.objects.all().order_by("title")
    ares = await async_query(str(query.query))
    results = [Model(**{
            "id": i[0],
            "title": i[1],
            "created": i[2].replace(tzinfo=None),
            "updated": i[3].replace(tzinfo=None)
        }) for i in ares]
    return {
        "data": ModelSerializer(results, many=True).data
    }
```

And then with apache bench just varied the number of concurrent requests and the total amount of requests, but with no change

Comment: Implicit in your question is the assumption that async *must* be faster. This is not necessarily true especially if the database can already use all processor threads and memory/cpu are constrained. You may just discover that doing 5 things simultaneously means each task takes 5 times as long resulting in no total reduction.

Comment: You know, I actually didn't think about that, I just presumed the connection could handle alot more traffic, reading up more I think you are right, its already at its limit regardless of sync or async